# The parameter is incorrect. at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, back

On Wp7 when the user presses the Start button on a page when the phone keyboard is displayed and hits device back button the app crashes with Exception as :-

```
The parameter is incorrect. 
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_TransformToVisual(UIElement element, UIElement visual)
   at System.Windows.Controls.SipHelper.AdjustFrame(FrameworkElement element, Double bottomMargin, Double& stillObscured)
   at System.Windows.Controls.SipHelper.SelectionChanged(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

I am not able to understand from where the exception is generated.

Thanks,
Kanaya

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. The keyboard is displayed because of which control, a textbox? If you create an empty project and put only that control, do you still have the issue?

Comment: No, it does not. I tried to follow the same thing. Also I tried to comment controls on the page one at a time and tested. It worked fine. But when the whole page was displayed I face the same issue again. From serching over internet I found various solutions like change listbox to itemscontol, remove textchanged, etc tried everything but still the exceptions there. Need to dig more.

Comment: If you manage to upload somewhere a project with that issue, I'll gladly help. Otherwise, I can't do much more unfortunately. Are you messing with the RootFrame somewhere? (in App.xaml.cs usually). If so, try removing these lines.

Answer (score 0):

it is happening because you are adding a control twice in page layout or adding any object twice to its parent.Check the code in OnNavigatedTO method.when you come back to your page  OnNavigatedTo is executed again so if you are adding any object to its parent in OnNavigatedTo method then you should remove that object from parent in OnNavigatedFrom function